# @EmbeddId is thowing org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated while using .save() frunction in hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a composite primary key in the table (table name: `billingdetails`, primary keys: `billId` and `productId`). When i call `../billingdetails/save` its throwing

> org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated.

Using postgres as backend

Entity class:

```
package com.acms.models;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonUnwrapped;


@Entity
@Table(name="billingdetails")
public class BillingDetails {
    @EmbeddedId
    @JsonUnwrapped
    private BillingDetailsEmbeddedId billingDetailsEmbeddedId;
    private int quantity;
    @Column(name = "mrp")
    private double cost;

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    public double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }
    public void setCost(double cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }
}
```

EmbeddedId class:

```
package com.acms.models;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;

@Embeddable
public class BillingDetailsEmbeddedId implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5911355292604736729L;
    @Column(name="billid")
    private int billId;
    @Column(name="productid")
    private String productId;
    public BillingDetailsEmbeddedId() {
        super();
    }
    public BillingDetailsEmbeddedId(int billId, String productId) {
        super();
        this.billId = billId;
        this.productId = productId;
    }
    public int getBillId() {
        return billId;
    }
    public void setBillId(int billId) {
        this.billId = billId;
    }
    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }
    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

}
```

Part of Service:

```
    public BillingDetails postData(BillingDetails billingDetails) {
        return this.billingDetailsRepository.save(billingDetails);
    }
```

Part of Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/billingdetails/save")
    public BillingDetails postData(BillingDetails billingDetails) {
        return billingDetailsService.postData(billingDetails);
    }
```

Postman request:

```
{
    "billId": "101",
    "productId":"p101",
    "quantity":"5",
    "cost":"500"
}
```

error log:

```
2020-04-27 21:44:01.500 ERROR 17032 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: null id generated for:class com.acms.models.BillingDetails; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class com.acms.models.BillingDetails] with root cause

org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class com.acms.models.BillingDetails
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:117) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:710) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:696) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:366) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy99.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:314) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy99.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:554) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:371) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:204) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:657) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:621) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy108.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.acms.services.BillingDetailsService.postData(BillingDetailsService.java:38) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.acms.services.BillingDetailsService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$be505737.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.acms.services.BillingDetailsService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$10a7f090.postData(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.acms.controllers.BillingDetailsController.postData(BillingDetailsController.java:57) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135) [na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [na:na]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `"billId"` instead of `"billid"` and `"productId"` instead of `"productID"` in request body.

You have to use the same name in requestbody as you define in Entity class for serialization and it's case sensitive.

Use @Embeddable on `BillingDetailsEmbeddedId` class

Comment: Doesn't that apply to "productID" as well?

Comment: @InsertKnowledge Yes I didn't notice that.Updated. Thanks

Comment: {
 "billId": "101",
 "productId":"p101",
 "quantity":"5",
 "cost":"500"
}

Comment: Can you add full error log in post ? and check the `billingDetails` data serialized properly logging in controller.

Comment: Use @Embeddable on BillingDetailsEmbeddedId class

Comment: Use @RequestBody  BillingDetails billingDetails in controller.